# Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. Still doesn't work even when replacing done() with returns

Tags: mongoose, mocha.js, chai, chai-http

I know I could use async or callbacks, but shouldn't promises work too?

My research has said all I should need to do is use return in place of done(); So I have done so, to the point where I probably have too many returns.

Still getting the 2000ms error though.

I converted these to callbacks (with done()) and it does work fine, but I just want to know where I have gone wrong with promises here.

```
chai.use(chaiHTTP);

describe('Users', () => {
  let UserId;
  before(() => {
    return mongoose.connect(

      'mongodb://localhost/testpromises',
      {},
      err => {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        return console.log('TEST DB Connection Success!!');
      }
    );
  });

  after(() => {
    return mongoose.connection.close();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    const newUser = new User({
      username: 'testuser',
      password: 'testuser'
    });
    return newUser
      .save()
      .then(savedUser => {
        userId = savedUser._id.toString();
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    return User.remove({ username: 'testuser' }, err => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
    });
  });

  describe(`[GET] /admin/users`, () => {
    it('should get the testuser account', () => {
      return chai
        .request(userRoutes)
        .get('/admin/users')
        .then(response => {
          expect(response.status).to.equal(200);
          expect(username).to.equal('testuser');
        })
        .catch(err => {
          throw err;
        });
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand after reading your code, the issue is probably with how you call `mongoose.connect(...)` in the `before` function.

`mongoose.connect()` either returns a promise or calls a callback if it is provided as the third parameter. ([mongoose.callback in the docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#callback)).

Your call to `connect` has a callback function, so probably what is returned is not a `promise` but `undefined`.

If that is true, then probably your test function starts to run before there's a connection and the combination of waiting for the connection and the request itself takes longer than 2000ms.

You should probably change `before` to something like this. `afterEach` has the same issue.

```
  before(() => {
    return mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/testpromises', {})
      .then(() => {
        console.log('TEST DB Connection Success!!')
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);            
      });
    );
  });
```